# How to pass parameters to OnClickListener?

Tags: android, onclicklistener

How can i pass parameter to an OnClickListener() ?

Got my Listener:

```
   OnClickListener myListener = new OnClickListener()
   {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v)
     {
         //I want to reach params here

     }

  };
```

I got 12 buttons and i dont want to write 12 listeners for them, it would be great to just pass a string to them and they can do completly different things.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Use your own custom OnClickListener

```
public class MyLovelyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener
   {

     int myLovelyVariable;
     public MyLovelyOnClickListener(int myLovelyVariable) {
          this.myLovelyVariable = myLovelyVariable;
     }

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v)
     {
         //read your lovely variable
     }

  };
```

Comment: Is there any advantage for this method over using a member variable and then assigning the value to it and accessing it inside the onClick? If yes what?

Comment: This answers the question though it also makes it obvious that the Listener should have been designed as a method not a full blown class. It would be so much simpler to pass anonymous method with custom args (e.g. View v)

Comment: this is the most clean, readable and easy to maintain solution. The advantage of the members inside - clearly indicates what the onClick method needs to work properly and enforce you to pass correct arguments when assigning it to a button. Don't forget you can use javadoc to describe the purpose of this particular listener and reuse it if you need it.

Answer (score 30):

**Another solution for that issue,** you can create a regular method and pass to it the `View` you want to add the `onClickListener` to it, and pass the **parameters** you want to use along with it:

```
Button b1 = new Button();
String something = "something";
Button b2 = new Button();
String anotherSomething = "anotherSomething";
setOnClick(b1, something);
setOnClick(b2, anotherSomething);

private void setOnClick(final Button btn, final String str){
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                  // Do whatever you want(str can be used here)

           }
    });
}
```

Comment: @vijayraj34 my pleasure :))

Answer (score 9):

I know this is a late answer but hopefully it can help someone. None of the existing answers worked in my situation but I ended up using the setTag feature of an image that was acting like a button. My account info was in a global member variable that was set up when the activity started.

In this case I am setting up a table with each row being an account. The account details are shown when the image is clicked (the image is just an info icon).
Thus:

```
// prior code....
// NOTE: oneAccount is an object (AccountInfo) holding information about the account

// column with the "detail" arrow
image1 = new ImageView(this);
image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.info);
image1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
image1.setPadding(15, 1, 15, 1);
image1.setTag(oneAccount);
// add a listener to go to that account detail on a click
image1.setOnClickListener(new TextView.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // change the color to signify a click
    v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.button_selected));


    // get what we need out of the tag
    AccountInfo thisAcct = (AccountInfo) v.getTag();

        // your code would do other stuff here

}
});

// add the image to the table row
tr1.addView(image1);
```

Comment: Cool stable approach :) can be used smoothly with data binding. thnx

Answer (score 8):

1. Have your activity implement View.OnClickListener
2. Register your buttons to the listener
3. Check which button is clicked in onClick
4. Process your string depending on which button was clicked

   ```
   public class _Test2Activity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

      private Button button1;
      private Button button2;
      private Button button3;

      private String myString;

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);   

        myString = "This is a string";

      } 

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          if(v==button1) {
             //do something with myString
          } else if(v==button2) {
             //do something with myString
          } else if (v==button3) {
             //do something with myString
          }
      }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you have static content associated with the view, another option is to use a `HashMap` to map the view id to the content.

```
private static Map<Integer, String> idToStringMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

Initialize the map in `onCreate`:

```
idToStringMap.put(R.id.button1, "hello");
idToStringMap.put(R.id.button2, "world");
// ...
```

Then get the value from the view id in `onClick`:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    String myString = idToStringMap.get(v.getId());
}
```

This is a little cleaner than using a long set of switch cases.

Answer (score 1):

**In Kotlin :**

Here i'm passing a **view as a parameter onClick** of Another view

define your **Handler** class object first in xml layout like this:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View" />
        <variable
            name="handler"
            type="com.demoapp.controllers.Handler" />
   </data>
```

and define button which **perform click** functionality.

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/button2"
  android:onClick="@{(view) -> handler.getbuttonClickEvent(textViewId)}"
  .../>
```

and your text view like this: 
remember your **TextView id** will be converted like **textViewId**

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_id"
        ... />
```

final set up method in your **Handler class**

```
fun getbuttonClickEvent(view: TextView){
        view.text="Hello World"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use implements OnClickListener like below code

```
public class Test extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    Button btn1;
    Button btn2;
    Button btn3;
    Button btn4;
    Button btn5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //initialize btn...~~~

        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn4.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn5.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case will be determine by Button's Id (R.id.blablabla)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you do this in Kotlin a little differently from how you do it in Java. In Kotlin, you append `NameOfParentClass()` to the subclass declaration.

Now override Activity‘s `onCreate()` method. It will look something like this.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        private var btnClick: Button? = null
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            btnClick = findViewById(R.id.btnClick) as Button
            btnClick!!.setOnClickListener { startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, KotlinActivity::class.java)) }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Another solution may be to not write the code directly inside onClick() method, alternatively, write the code in a separate method, and then call that method in onClick().

Example:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    function();
   }
});

private void function() {
 //your code here
}
```

Comment: Ok, but the question specifies clearly the need to pass parameters

Comment: that won't enable him to pass parameters