# Android - toggleButton delay with own OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, togglebutton

I have problem with unwanted delay after click on toggleButton using own OnClickListener.
I make my listener by this [advice on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614696/how-to-pass-parameters-to-onclicklistener), like below:

```
public class ToggleButtonOnClickListener implements OnClickListener{

    private String _name;

    public ToggleButtonOnClickListener(String name) {
        _name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i("toggle button clicked",_name);
    }
}
```

and using this:

```
toggle.setOnClickListener(new ToggleButtonOnClickListener(device.GetName()));
```

But it not fire onClick method after first click, but the next one.
And because I have group of toggleButtons is this very unhappy, when I click on first, and onClick method fire after click again or even after click to second (or any) from the group.
The OnCheckChangeListener behaves the same.

Comment: @iDroidExplorer well I didn't find any onTogglechangeListener. And I don't need to click event, as I said in last sentese - OnCheckChangeListener don't work as I hoped.

Comment: Yes SOrry, Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking for errors and testing other options, I found that delay caused not Listener, but the log statement.
So, the code above working well except for

```
Log.i("toggle button clicked",_name);
```

and an alternative without needs have own class(parametrs) using OnCheckedChangeListener is:

```
toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        Toast.makeText(buttonView.getContext(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

I don't know why this Log do, but I used them only for debug, so problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [developer's example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html).

You can implement something like below:

```
 public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
    // Is the toggle on?
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

    if (on) {
        // Enable vibrate
    } else {
        // Disable vibrate
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I've read this example, but I don't know how this can help me?
I still have to put this method to OnClick or OnCheckChange Listeners, right? But the event fired belatedly. Or I overlooked something?