# How do I pass the additional parameter to the onClick method?

Tags: android

I want to pass a from my method to the button clicked method.

Method that generates a:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
             String str = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();

             double a = 0;

             switch(arg2){

             case 0:
                  a = 4;
                 break;

             case 1:
                 a = 3.75;
                 break;

             case 2:
                 a = 3.50;
                 break;

             case 3:
                 a = 3.25;
                 break;
             case 4:
                 a = 3;
                 break;
             case 5:
                 a = 2.75;
                 break;
             case 6:
                 a = 2.5;
                 break;
             case 7:
                 a = 2.25;
                 break;


             }
```

Button clicked method

```
public void button(View v){

}
```

Comment: there is no question here

Comment: where is your "button method" ?

Comment: You are falling victim to scope. You need to make a's scope the entire class instead of just your method. See MrEngineer13's answer for how to move it to a class field variable. Long story short, move the declaration for a to just inside of your activity class scope.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614696/how-to-pass-parameters-to-onclicklistener/10614751#10614751

Shows you how to create your own click listener in to which you can pass additional paramaters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make `a` a field of your activity instead of an instance variable like so:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

double a = 0;

...

}
```

Comment: What code? all you need to change in your code is to cut `double a = 0;` line and paste it at the top of your activity class