# Call method which needs parameters using android:onClick in XML

Tags: android, xml, onclick

I have a `Button` and it is defined in XML. I am using `android:onClick` to call a method called `showMessage`. Simple method example:

```
    public void showMessage(View v){
    Log.w(TAG, "Hi");
    }
```

Now suppose my method needs for example a **boolean** and an **int** as parameters, how to do something like:

`android:onClick="showMessage(boolean isExpensive, int money)"`

Comment: It does not work that way AFAIK. Using a callback from the layout's XML is limited. If you want something more complex, simply on `View.setOnClickListener()`.

Comment: You Cannot do it. Onclick is the inbuild method of android which has only one param that is clicked view.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass parameters to OnClickListener?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614696/how-to-pass-parameters-to-onclicklistener). A **brilliant solution** is shown.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I knew I couldn't do it, i was just looking for a work around.
@DerGolem I understand the example if I had to call my method in the code, but can't quite get how to use it in my XML situation. Can you be more specific please? :)

Comment: Exactly as @yaa110 showed you-

Answer (score 12):

It is not possible to pass parameters as you did, but you can use tags:

```
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:tag="false,25"
    android:onClick="showMessage"
/>

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:tag="true,50"
    android:onClick="showMessage"
/>
```

and in your java:

```
public void showMessage(View v) {
    String tag = v.getTag().toString();
    boolean isExpensive = Boolean.parseBoolean(tag.split(",")[0]);
    int money = Integer.parseInt(tag.split(",")[1]);
    this.showMessage(isExpensive, money);
}

public void showMessage(boolean isExpensive, int money) {
    // Your codes here
}
```

Comment: This may actually do the trick, I will try it and will give some feedback tomorrow :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier to use an onclicklistener?

Define the button with id:

```
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        /.. more attributes here ../
        android:text="@string/something" />
```

and in your activity:

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Hi");
        }});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:
 Define another function in the activity.java without the argument.
Call this function from the button click.

Make your actual function with the the argument you want to pass.

```
public void showMessageToClick(View v){
    // define your bool as per your need
    boolean isExpensive = true;
    int money=30000;

    showMessage(isExpensive, money)
    Log.w(TAG, "Hi");
} 

showMessage(boolean isExpensive, int money){
   // your code here
}
```