# Why do I get an error statement when using an if comparison of ids

Tags: java, android

I make a Button and I want to make onClick method in XML

```
    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:onClick="maysara"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginTop="63dp" />
```

Then I go to Java code to make the method "maysara"

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}

public void maysara(View v){
**if(v.getId()==findViewById(R.id.button2))**
    Toast.makeText(this,"button2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}}
```

But I got an error in if statement >>> I really dont know why @?!

Comment: why you set `if(v.getId()==findViewById(R.id.button2))`

Comment: `v.getId()== R.id.button2`

Comment: Primary opinion based question

Comment: I use if because I make two Button which use the same method "maysara"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27192219/call-method-which-needs-parameters-using-androidonclick-in-xml

Comment: your solution work with me 
But can I  know why _ findViewById _ doesnt work ??!!

Comment: `if(v.getId().equals(button2)) {} else{}`

Comment: `findViewById(id)` returns a `View`. `v.getId()` returns an ID, not a view. You don't need to find the view for the id. You can just compare the IDs

Comment: @MrsEd I have deleted the project so I Can't include my logcat

Comment: And I feel very happy coz my question now have -3 review 
it was -4 
:) :) :) 
LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the return type of findViewById() which is a view and you are comparing with v.getId() which is id. You should not compare this.

> public View findViewById (int id)

Answer (score 0):

Just use like this

```
public void maysara(View v){
 Toast.makeText(this,"button2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

It help you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has an answer, but I thought I'd add one.

You are declaring

```
android:onClick="maysara"
```

as the onClick method in your xml for this button. 
There is no need to do a check on which button is clicking, as you have explicitly defined this in your xml.

So within your `mayasara` method, you only need to show what you want to do, not a check on the button clicking.

```
public void maysara(View v){


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:onClick="maysara"


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:onClick="maysara"
```

A switch statement is a much better option, as you do not need to check for the value of `R.id.button2` as you have in your if statement. Checking those values for this type of function is a clumsy way of programming.

```
public void maysara(View v){
    switch(v.getId()) {
       case R.id.button1:
        // to do
       break;
       case R.id.button2:
        // to do
       break;
```