# Easier way pass the activity "this" pointer to setOnClickListener?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Simple one, I need to access a global variable from inside a onClickListener, but the instance has no knowledge of the "this" pointer. Is there an easy way to do this:

```
    activityButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.actbtn);
    activityButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (fragmentCommunicator != null) {
                // cannot really do this. I need to pass the "this pointer"
                int counter = ((MyApplication) this.getApplication()).getGlobalCounter();                    counter++;
                fragmentCommunicator.passDataToFragment("Hi from activity!, global counter = " + counter);
            }

        }
```

I tried as a custom OnClickListener

[How to pass parameters to OnClickListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614696/how-to-pass-parameters-to-onclicklistener)

but is there a compact syntax? In cpp++ the would be the equivalent of lambda capture [=]

thx!

Comment: remove `this.` and it can access the method

Comment: If you didn't remove `this.` you would replace it with `YourActivityName.this.getApplication()`.

Comment: did you try getActivity().getApplication() etc....?

Comment: where the code is implemented, in an Activity,fragment..?

Comment: btw there's no such thing as a global variable in Java.