# View being passed as a parameter in Kotlin/Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-view

New to kotlin/android so excuse my beginner skills.

However, why is `View` being passed in `onClick(v: View)` where the `type` should usually be? (e.g `Int`, `String`) etc.

I didn't think this was possible/allowed.

My code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener  {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        choose_1_player.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View) {

        when (v.id){
            R.id.choose_1_player -> println("Hello")
            R.id.choose_2_player -> println("Hello")
        }

    }


}
```

Is it because the [function](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener) is written in Java and not Kotlin?

Comment: `View` is a type. `View` is a class name, same as `String` for example

Comment: Why did you think `View` wasn't a type?

Comment: Thanks @VladyslavMatviienko that clears it up.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov because I didn't think you could just create new custom classes and make them types (like `View`), I thought these were the only possible data types: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html

Answer (score 2):

Because

1.We click on a `View` it may be a `Button` , `TextView` ,`EditText` or any layout  so on the basis of Integer ID difficult to match with actual views.

2.`View` has many information including its Id ,that can be used like (Tag , Text  etc).

3.Also view has its parent Layout Information can be used .

Please find more details at below link:

[Why do we have to add 'View' as parameter in onClick method and what it does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37682776/why-do-we-have-to-add-view-as-parameter-in-onclick-method-and-what-it-does)

View `class` has `interface` with method `onClick(View view)`.

```
/**
     * Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a view is clicked.
     */
    public interface OnClickListener {
        /**
         * Called when a view has been clicked.
         *
         * @param v The view that was clicked.
         */
        void onClick(View v);
    }
```

Comment: I'm mainly asking about the syntax of the parameter: `(v: View)` (because I'm writing in Kotlin) - `View` isn't a data type and that position usually holds a data type (parameterName: dataType)

Answer (score 1):

`MainActivity` class is implementing `View.OnClickListener` interface, which has the following signature:

```
public interface OnClickListener {
    void onClick(View v);
}
```

So `onClick` method is implemeted and it receives `View` as the parameter.

`v` - is a view which was clicked.

---

**Addition**:
The syntax of the overridden `onClick` method in Kotlin is the following:

```
override fun onClick(v: View) { ... }
```

where `v` - is a view which was clicked; `View` - is the data type of object `v` from Android SDK. It is a parent class for many children, such as `Button`, `TextView` etc. That means `onClick` method can receive a `Button`, `TextView`, `ImageView` and other views that inherit from `View`. Here works one of the principles of OOP - **Polymorphism**.

Comment: I'm mainly asking about the syntax of the parameter: `(v: View)` (because I'm writing in Kotlin) - `View` isn't a data type and that position usually holds a data type `(parameterName: dataType)`

Comment: `View` is a data Type from Android SDK. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The View attribute inform which View you clicked (every visual component of Android is a View) so you can use this information to identify "who" is calling the onClick.

If in my layout I have 3 buttons (button1, button2, button3) I can do something like this (in Java):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener  {
...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);

        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch(view.id) {
            case R.id.button1:
                button1Action();
            break;

            case R.id.button2:
                button2Action();
            break;

            case R.id.button3:
                button3Action();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Or you can do something like this and ignore the View attribute

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                button1Action();
            }
        });
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                button2Action();
            }
        });
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                button3Action();
            }
        });
    }
```

PS.: I didn't run this code. Probably it has some errors.