# How To Set OnClickListener For This Custom Adapter?

Tags: android, onclicklistener

### Hello Dears . Thank you For Reply This question . How Can i SetOnClick Listener For every position of this list view ? thanks !!!

public class fragment_1 extends Fragment {

```
ListView list;

public fragment_1() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
    list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity() , text , imageId);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

> Here i need help

```
    return rootView;
}
```

And This is My Custom Adapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Activity _context;
private final String[] _text;
private final String[] _imageId;

public CustomAdapter(Activity context, String[] text, String[] imageId) {
    super(context, R.layout.fragment2, text);
    this._context = context;
    this._text = text;
    this._imageId = imageId;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = _context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.collection_custom_adapter, null, true);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.collection_text);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.collection_image);
    txtTitle.setText(_text[position]);
    Picasso.with(_context).load(_imageId[position]).into(imageView);

    return rowView;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass parameters to OnClickListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614696/how-to-pass-parameters-to-onclicklistener)

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your activity after setting adapter:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.